# Multiplicity of zeros and derivatives.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I know that if $r$ is a root of $p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ of multiplicity $k+1$, then $p^{(j)}(r)=0$, for every $j\leq k$, where $p^{(j)}$ stands for the $j$-th derivative of the function $x\mapsto p(x)$.

> Conversely, if $p(r)=p^{(1)}(r)=\dots=p^{(k)}(r)=0$, then does $(x-r)^{k+1}$ divide $p$?

If yes, then

> Is there a notion of multiplicity for arbitrary functions? What about some relation with zeros of its derivatives?

Thank you.

Comment: The converse is not true in the sense that $p^{(k)}(r)=0$ does not even impty that $r$ is a root. - For arbitrary functions, how do you define multiplicity of a root?

Comment: The converse is true. Not necessarily true for any function that is not in a polynomial field. For example, it wouldn't make much sense to talk about the degree of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: And the converse is only true if both $p(r)=0$ and $p^k (r) = 0$.

Comment: Alright, that's what I intended to write: "if $p^{(j)}(r)=0$ for every $j\leq k$, then does $(x-r)^{k+1}$ divide $p$?". I'll fix it. For arbitrary functions, I haven't thought of a definition of "multilicity", but I was thinking about a "stronger" kind of zero.